# SQL to Linq query with multiple left outer joins

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to convert an `SQL query` to `Linq` containing several left outer joins, but I'm encountering an odd situation.

The relevant part of my SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SessionDetails as sd
    left outer join dbo.VoipDetails as vd on vd.SessionIdTime = sd.SessionIdTime and vd.SessionIdSeq = sd.SessionIdSeq
    left outer join dbo.Gateways as fgw on vd.FromGatewayId = fgw.GatewayId
```

My Linq query so far is:

```
var query = from sd in dbo.SessionDetails
    join vd in dbo.VoipDetails on new { sd.SessionIdTime, sd.SessionIdSeq } equals new { vd.SessionIdTime, vd.SessionIdSeq } into sdvd
    from v in sdvd.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join fgw  in dbo.Gateways on vd.FromGatewayId equals fgw.GatewayId   into sdgw
         from g in sdvd.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select sd;
```

I'm getting an error mark on `vd.FromGatewayId` telling me that `The name 'vd' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.`
However, if I do swap sides with `gw.GatewayId` then  I get the same error message for both `vd` and `gw`.
Can someone suggest the correct syntax here?
Please bear in mind I have several more left-joins to add after I get the basic syntax down.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that you are trying to access a value that has no scope in the query.  I believe the reason for this is that you specify the relation ship and then assign these values to a collection called `sdvd` at this point you can't get to vd.  That said, you then do `from v in sdvd.DefaultIfEmpty()` by doing so you have access to the rows in sdvd which are the same values that are in what you think `vd` holds.  You should be able to use `v` instead of `vd`.  I had to mock something up to test so I couldn't test out exactly this query, but the following should run.

```
var query = from sd in dbo.SessionDetails
    join vd in dbo.VoipDetails on new { sd.SessionIdTime, sd.SessionIdSeq } equals new { vd.SessionIdTime, vd.SessionIdSeq } into sdvd
    from v in sdvd.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join fgw  in dbo.Gateways on v.FromGatewayId equals fgw.GatewayId   into sdgw
        from g in sdvd.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select sd;
```

EDIT 2014/12/08

In order to see how the linq statement translates to sql, I would suggest you install https://www.linqpad.net/.  You can set up a connection and test out your queries there and see the sql in the results view.

As i don't have the data structure for the question this will be hard. That said I mocked up something:

```
from sd in  Employees
    join vd in TimeEntries on new { sd.EmployeeID } equals new { vd.EmployeeID } into sdvd
    from v in sdvd.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join fgw  in EmployeeGroupDetails on v.EmployeeID equals fgw.EmployeeID   into sdgw
        from g in sdgw.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select  sd
```

This YIELDS:

```
SELECT [t0].*
FROM [Employee] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [TimeEntry] AS [t1] ON [t0].[EmployeeID] = [t1].[EmployeeID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [EmployeeGroupDetail] AS [t2] ON [t1].[EmployeeID] = [t2].[EmployeeID]
```

It does come back with the right joins.

Comment: I might well be misunderstanding, but in order to continue to make left-outer-joins, shouldn't that be `on v.FromGatewayId equals fgw.GatewayId   into sdgw from g in sdgw.DefaultIfEmpty()` rather than `sdvd.DefaultIfEmpty()` again?